# New row when displaying every new echo $row ['username']

Tags: php, mysql, html, web, authentication

I want if is possible to display the username in a new row instead of one next to the other.

e.g.:

```
admin
user1
user2                                                          
admin                       
user1                 
user2
```

Here is my code:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('chatbox',$con);
$sql    = "SELECT `username` 
       FROM `users` 
       ORDER BY `username` ASC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


if($result === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['username']; //over here
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh please `echo $row['username'] . "<br>";`

Comment: @WilliamJanoti `\n` will only display in a new line in HTML source and not during display. Or, if saved in a file. `\n` will only show a space on screen and not a new line. `\n` is good if added to it `echo $row['username'] . "<br>" . "\n";` which will produce clean HTML and a new line on screen.

Comment: @WilliamJanoti You're welcome. Oh, and same thing for PHP_EOL ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either

```
echo $row['username'] . "<br>" . "\n";
```

or

```
echo $row['username'] . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
```

which will produce both clean HTML and new lines on screen for each word/name.

***Sidenote:*** It's important to use double quotes for the `\n`. If not and using single quotes such as `'\n'` will echo `n` which is not what you want. Therefore, use `"\n"`.

---

**Nota:** `\n` and `PHP_EOL` will only produce new lines/carriage returns in HTML source and not on screen, which I believe is what the ultimate goal is.

Plus, if used when writing files, will place them on seperate lines.

Therefore, you need to add `<br>` for your purpose.

---

***Footnotes:***

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

- Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements),
  *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following as your while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['username'], "<br/>", PHP_EOL;//over here
}
```

`PHP_EOL` specifies a platform independent new line character.

Comment: `echo $row['username']  . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;` - what you have now `echo $row['username'], PHP_EOL;` will only show them in new lines in HTML source only and not on screen.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: `mysql` function is deprecated since PHP 5.5, so you have to move to `mysqli` function.

If you want to use `foreach` approachment, then it should be like this:

```
<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($row as $key => $value) echo $row['username'].PHP_EOL;
```